# GNOME Shell Integration (menus)

Tags: interface, linux

Is there an Add-On that enables GNOME's (also Unity's) native menus?

I mean the menu's in the Info panel like File, Render, Window, Help.

---

> Current Look
>
> [image: Current Look]
>
> Desired Look
>
> [image: Desired Look]

Comment: Blender uses its own native UI drawing and cross platform library, it does not integrate into any OS or toolkit as far as I know

Comment: There's integration on Windows at least. Like render-progress on taskbar icon. I thought maybe a python extension could interact with gnome

Comment: Yes, but that is Blender data that is "externalized" into the Windows part of UI, not the other way around, no native windows menus are drawn inside Blender

Comment: Maybe with a python extenion it would still be possible to kind of 'fake' the blender internal menus and make the faked ones do the same as the blender internals. For example open a file chooser for opening a project or starting the rendering progress. Then you could simply hide or move the info panel yourself

Comment: I suspect that you could write some code that would grab the Blender context and wrap it in an OS window, if that would satisfy your objective...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Basically No

No, it's not possible and never will be (in all likelihood).

Blender is basically just one OpenGL Canvas, that uses OpenGL to draw all of its UI using it's own library called GHOST, see [Is the Blender GUI package available for other programs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1261/12).

Maybe it will be more clear by comparing Blender to a video game using OpenGL (which is essentially the same thing, a pure OpenGL application):
You are asking to put GNOME's menus into Counter Strike/WoW/you name it.

It just won't work because OpenGL is not operating with the normal windowing system of your OS.
Other 3D software like Maya / 3ds max use the native windowing system and only use DirectX/OpenGL to render the 3D Views. Blender as a whole is just one (or more) big OpenGL window(s).

### Alternatives

#### Create additional GNOME windows via python

You could use python to create additional windows using GNOME's native menus, which could then interact with Blender. But that would just be a bad idea, because you'd get into a lot of cross-platform trouble, plus it's inconsistent with the rest of Blender and I don't even know a single project that does something like that.

#### Use Blender as a python module

If you just want use some functionality of Blender (maybe to modify a lot of blend files in a specific way) and want a GNOME UI then you could use Blender as a python module. That's a bit more involved though. [For more info have a look at the Blender Wiki page on using Blender as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=User%3AIdeasman42%2FBlenderAsPyModule)

Comment: Great answer! Concider yourself upvoted (i don't have the reputition at the moment) I'm already working on a python extension. Your information will be very useful for creating it